# Python Pandas Plot has Gaps when using Sparse Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

When I try to plot the following data

```
import pandas as pd
dfx = pd.DataFrame()
dfx['bing'] = [1,2,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
dfx['bang'] = [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,4,5,6,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
dfx['boo'] = [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,7,8,9]
dfx.plot()
plt.show()
```

I get this line with gaps. I want to be able to make use of the different colors for different segments of my line, but would like it to be "connected" as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible ideas:

**Option 1:** Use [`df.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dfx = pd.DataFrame()
dfx['bing'] = [1,2,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
dfx['bang'] = [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,4,5,6,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
dfx['boo'] = [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,7,8,9]

dfx.fillna(method='bfill', axis=1).plot()
plt.show()

# i.e. we're plotting:

array([[ 1., nan, nan],
       [ 2., nan, nan],
       [ 3., nan, nan],
       [ 4.,  4., nan],
       [ 5.,  5., nan],
       [ 6.,  6., nan],
       [ 7.,  7.,  7.],
       [ 8.,  8.,  8.],
       [ 9.,  9.,  9.]])
```

Result:

[image: plot with fillna]

**Option 2:** Add line to connect the other lines

A bit more work (though there may be a quicker way to construct the "connector" line than the approach I'm using here). Add a column that connects end of one line with start of the next. E.g.:

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame()
dfx['bing'] = [1,2,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
dfx['bang'] = [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,4,5,6,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
dfx['boo'] = [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,7,8,9]

# get index vals end-start: array([2, 3, 5, 6], dtype=int64)
s = dfx.apply(lambda col: (col.first_valid_index(), 
                           col.last_valid_index()))\
    .stack().sort_values().to_numpy()[1:-1]

# create extra col with connection btw consecutive lines
dfx['connect'] = dfx.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1).iloc[:,-1]\
    .mask(~dfx.index.isin(s))

# print(dfx.connect.to_numpy())
# [nan nan  3.  4. nan  6.  7. nan nan]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))

colors = ['blue','orange','green','black']
for i, col in enumerate(dfx.columns):
    if col == 'connect':
        # add `label=col` if you want "connect" in the legend as well
        ax.plot(dfx[col], colors[i], linestyle='dotted')
    else:
        ax.plot(dfx[col], colors[i], label=col)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: plot with connector line]